# How to set a data for a particular row in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I made a login page were I am getting user Email id,  and then I am generating a otp and sending to the user mail. Now I want to save the generated otp in database to the particular user by using his mailid. But the problem is when I am saving otp in database it is not storing in the given mailid, and I am not able to figure it out.

My code:

SendOtp code :

```
public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        
    //  int otp = random.nextInt(999999);

        String otp = RandomString.make(8);
        
        String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
        String toEmail = email;
        String body = "OTP :  " + otp;
        
             
        SessionHandling sessionHandling = new SessionHandling();
        sessionHandling.setOneTimePassword(otp);
        repo.save(sessionHandling);
        
           this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
          return ("success");
```

Database :

```
Id | password | emailid             | name    | Cpass      |  otp              | time

8 | 123        | shy@gmail.com      | shymm   | 123        | NULL              | NULL               
9 | NULL       | NULL               | NULL    | NULL       | Wi0ioiuZ          | NULL   
10 | NULL       | NULL               | NULL    | NULL       | R98RT1OZ          | NULL
```

When I had tried storing otp it made new row  i.e 9 & 10.

Comment: What do you think `new SessionHandling()` with a subsequent `repo.save(sessionHandling);` will do? How do you think the repository would know it should update a specific record instead of adding a new one? - One thing you could do is first read the record by mail id, then add the OTP and save it again. Or use an update query so you don't have to read.

Comment: That's it, a new row is created as you create a new object ( new `SessionHandling `). Do you use JPA repositories?

Comment: Btw, you're probably doing this for learning purposes so keep it simple. But when doing this in production you'd have a big security hole in that design: the OTP (and any other password) should _never_ be stored in plain text but rather be hashed and salted so only the user knows it.

Comment: @Jedupont yes i have made Repository class

Comment: @Thomas now for learning purpose I am storing password directly.

Comment: @Thomas can you tell me how can I update ? Can you give me the syntax of it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained by @Thomas, you should always hash your passwords in production.

However, here is an example to update the otp using JPA repositories:

```java
@Repository
public interface SessionHandlingRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionHandling, Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE SessionHandling s SET s.otp = :otpCode WHERE s.id = :id")
    void updateOtp(@Param("id") Long whereId, @Param("otpCode") String otp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to store data in sessionhandling class related to that particular emailId and then set otp and save it.

Make repository class with method **findByEmailID()** in it.

**xyzrepo.class**

```
@Query(value = "Select * from sessionhandling where emailId=?1",nativeQuery = true)
SessionHandling findByEmailId(String emailId);
```

And Your method SendOtp look like:

```
//Autowired xyzrepo

public String sendOtp(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        
    //  int otp = random.nextInt(999999);

        String otp = RandomString.make(8);
        
        String subject = "OTP from session-handling-proj By Harshit";
        String toEmail = email;
        String body = "OTP :  " + otp;
        
             
        SessionHandling sessionHandling = xyzrepo.findByEmailId(email);
        sessionHandling.setOneTimePassword(otp);
        repo.save(sessionHandling);
        
           this.emailService.sendMail(toEmail, subject, body);
          return ("success");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 cases  :
**Case 1**  : do you save only one record for mail Id or may have many records for each login operation.
based on your business will create the query
if only one record :
and you are sure that email exists in Db please use this code

```
@Repository
public interface SessionHandlingRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionHandling, Long> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE SessionHandling s SET s.otp = :otpCode WHERE s.emailid= :emailId")
    void updateOtp(@Param("emailId") String mailId, @Param("otpCode") String otp);
}
```

If you are not sure,

So  you have to save a new Record for all details

**case 2:**   many records allowed for mail  :
so you also have to create a new record for SessionHandling  for  emailed and new Otp